# What is the difference between inner and outer exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone explain to me what the differences are. Is it true that inner exception lives on stack and outer lives on heap?

Comment: There is normal exception, which can contains inner, which can contains inner... There is no outer exception.

Comment: Can you provide and example for Inner and Outer Exceptions ?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I believe all exceptions must exist on the heap. In addition to the fact that exceptions are reference types, which always exist on the heap, you've got to unwind the stack to find the nearest catch block, so it wouldn't make sense for the exception to live there.

Comment: How could any exception exist on the stack?  When the exception is created, it's not known at what point in the call stack the exception will be handled (or even if it will only be handled at one place in the call stack.)  Besides, why would it matter?

Comment: It was a question asked by my friend which I did not know answer to. Of course I googled and searched to make sure it was not asked before here or anywhere else. Whether it is correct or wrong question, it still is a question that can arise and confuse people like myself.

Answer (score 1):

The "inner" exception is a "nested" or "wrapped" exception that contains additional information about the exception (called "outer") that occurred. It is actually the cause of the outer exception. I hope the next quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) clarifies your question.

> When a causal relationship exists between two or more exceptions, the InnerException property maintains this information. The outer exception is thrown in response to this inner exception. The code that handles the outer exception can use the information from the earlier inner exception to handle the error more appropriately. Supplementary information about the exception can be stored as a collection of key/value pairs in the Data property.

Comment: Do you know where they live in memory?

Comment: @DoodleKana: Exceptions are reference types and therefore the instance lives on the heap. (Note that this is NOT the statement "value types live on the stack", because that is false.) Now, the *reference* can be stored somewhere else; don't forget that *where the house is* and *where the map that shows you where the house is* are two very different things. References are data that is distinct from the thing they refer to.